# XSLT - Concatenate element attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to find a way a simple way to combine multiple attributes on an element into a single, delimited attribute using XSLT.

A simplified example of what I'm trying to do what be, given an XML element like this:

```
<div border='none' padding='0' margin='0></div>
```

the XSLT should return (note the spaces)

```
<div style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0;"></div>
```

I can't seem to do this with <xsl:template match="@border"> as only one of the attributes gets transformed.

These attributes can be on virtually element and need to work with existing element templates (i.e. I can't just do it in the identity transform).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These attributes can be on virtually element and need to work with
>   existing element templates

It's difficult to advise without seeing what those templates do. It would probably be best to have a named template like this:

```
<xsl:template name="css">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

and call it from any template where you need it, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="css"/>
        <!-- YOUR EXISTING TEMPLATE CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added:

Alternatively, you could have a template matching the individual style attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="@border | @padding | @margin">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:for-each select="../@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

But you would still have to apply templates to (at least) one of the attributes from the context of the parent element:

```
<xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[1]"/>
        <!-- YOUR EXISTING TEMPLATE CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The templates just convert various XML elements to HTML elements. I could make a named template and call it from every template matching a node, but I was hoping there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: @TheCommunistCow The only other way I can think of would work only if all the elements affected had at least one common style attribute (e.g. border), and you had a list of all other possible style attributes that may appear in the input.

Comment: There's only a relatively small number of attributes (5 or so) that would be getting merged, so I do have a list of all of them. However, they can appear in any combination. Could you describe or post a link that shows what you have in mind? Thanks.